# Split Name, Date and quantity in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to split my filename `(14-07-2022-Pencil-200 (Zane))` using vb.net

```
Date: 14-07-2022
Product : Pencil
Quantity : 200
Buyer : Zane
```

Result :

```
TextBox 1 : 14-7-2022
TextBox 2 : Pencil
TextBox 3 : 200
TextBox 4 : Zane
```

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? It's not for us to teach you how to program or write your code for you. If you haven't tried then you don't know that you can't do it, so there's no issue for us to address.

Comment: This is the filename? `(14-07-2022-Pencil-200 (Zane))`. However, use the `System.IO.Path` methods to get the filenamewithoutextension. Use `System.String` methods to get the tokens. For example the date has always 10 letters, so you could use `String.Remove(10)`. The remaining parts(`String.Substring(10)`) are separated by `-`, so use `String.Split`.

Comment: 14-07-2022-Pencil-200 (Zane) this is actually file name. I want to extract name, date and quantity to each textboxes. Like TxtBox1: Name, Textbox2: Date like that.

Comment: Look into string.split.  If you split on "-" you will have 5 separate strings to use (assuming always this format). Clean up as needed (remove ( from first string, split last on space to access final elements).   Or use string.replace to replace brackets with hyphens, then split on hyphens and put back together as needed.  Your choice but try it, and if you struggle, post your code for specific help.

Comment: Where can spaces appear?  Product?  Buyer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Left(), instr() or substring() functions.
I can give you logic - i don't know which are exact function names in vb.net.
Logic is:

1. Use left(filename,10) go get date. (here : 14-07-2022)
2. Use substr() or relative function starting from character 11 to last occurrence of "-". this will give you Product Name (here : Pencil)
3. again user substring starting from last occurrence of "-" to first occurrence of character space (" "). (here : 200)
4. Use again substring starting from first occurrence of character "(" to end of file name string. (here : Zane)